# Wordpress tinymce insert text

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I have problem with tinymce in wordpress. I need to put inside tinymce element . In tinymce editor where are two tabs "Visual" and "HTML". When I use my code in "HTML" its works. But when I want to use in "Visual" its not working...

I was trying like this:

**JavaScript**

```
function insert_tag(text){
    var cont = document.getElementById('bbp_topic_content');
    cont.value += '<div>' + text + '</div>';
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a onclick="insert_tag('HELLO')" >Insert text</a>
```

Any help please ?

Comment: You should create a plugin for `tinyMCE` for this kind of work. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012394/adding-button-to-trigger-html-code-fragment-into-tinymce-editor-via-jquery/14012747#14012747) to get an idea.

Comment: Where is no any simple way ? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may try this

```
function insert_tag(text){
    if(tinyMCE && tinyMCE.activeEditor)
    {
        tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.setContent('<div>' + text + '</div>');
    }
    return false;
}
```

Also use `return` in your `a` tag

```
<a onclick="return insert_tag('HELLO')" >Insert text</a>
```

[Reference](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3amethod.tinymce.dom.Selection.setContent).